# Rollback only affected rows

Tags: laravel, database-migration

I am filling the `published_at` information in the `migration` like so:

```
Blog::all()->each(function($blog) {
    if($blog->published_at == null) {
       $blog->update(['published_at' => $blog->created_at]);
     }
});
```

The question is: how should my `down() function` look like? I cannot just

```
Blog::all()->each(function($blog) {
    $blog->update(['published_at' => null]);
});
```

because then I would lose all my `published_at` datas, including the `published_at` datas that have been the before running migration.

Comment: If you want to keep all dates that a blogpost has been (un)published, you will have to create a second table that holds all these dates. Then, create a one-to-many relation from blogpost to this table.

Comment: Could you check if `$blog->published_at === $blog->created_at` and only set those ones to `null`? Might not be perfect, but would limit the `null`s

Comment: why you are updating? maybe you need a new column to track this event. Or you can check if the published_at is equal created_at: `if($blog->created_at == $blog->published_at){ $blog->update...`

Comment: @Jerodev yeah, I have been considering such solutions but seemed like hard work for a little thing to me.

Comment: The comparing those 2 information looks pretty easy and should work as expected. Thanks for suggestions